# How to save all but one field in Doctrine + ZF2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have a User entity and in the edit Action I present a form to edit the user. I would like to have a password field available. If the password is blank, then I would like to update all field except the password, and if something is entered then all fields would be updated.

Here is my controller action.

```
public function editUserAction() {
    $id = (int) $this->params()->fromRoute('id', 0);
    if (!id) return $this->redirect()->toRoute('index', array('action' => 'users));
    $objectManager = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager');
    $form = new UserForm($objectManager);
    $user = $objectManager->find('Application\Entity\User', $id);
    $form->bind($user);
    if ($this->request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($this->request->getPost());
        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $data = $this->request->getPost();
            if ($data->user['password'] == '') {
                // how to save all but one field
            }
            else {
                $objectManager->persist($user);
                $objectManager->flush();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the remove method:

vendor/zendframework/zendframework/library/Zend/Form/Fieldset.php
remove  Remove a named element or fieldset 
Parameters:
 
string
$elementOrFieldset
PHPDoc not found
Returns:
 
Type:
FieldsetInterface

```
if ($data->user['password'] == '') 
{

        $form->remove('password');
        $objectManager->persist($user);
        $objectManager->flush();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you got me on the right track, but this was still saving an empty password for the user.